# Count of A Column For Last 12 Months and Individual Month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a bit complex requirement and for the understanding, let me make it clear with easy example. Suppose, we have to calculate the quantity of products purchased by consumers month-wise for the last 12 months. So what we do is the following:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, m.InvoiceDate) Month,
COUNT(m.Quantity) Quantity FROM CustomerInvoice m WHERE 
DATEDIFF(month, m.InvoiceDate, GETDATE()) <= 12 AND YEAR(m.InvoiceDate) = '2018'
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, m.InvoiceDate)
ORDER BY DATENAME(MONTH, m.InvoiceDate) DESC;
```

**Output** - So this is what we get:

```
Month       Quantity
January     1
February    1
March       1
April       2
May         1
June        3
July        1
August      2
```

In my case, it's bit complicated as the following sample:

[image: Sample Output]
So if the input is `July 2018`, it should calculate the last 12 months quantity or value as well individual month's last 12 months value too. This seems to be something like recursive call. But pretty unsure how to accomplish this in the right way - Any ideas or samples would be highly appreciated - Thanks.

**Sample Table With Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerInvoice](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL,
    [Details] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [InvoiceID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
    [InvoiceDate] [datetime] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (1, 2, 2, N'Awesome Collections', N'20151129115910', 1, CAST(0x0000A94200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (2, 1, 2, N'Joss Collections', N'20151129115910', 1, CAST(0x0000A94200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (3, 2, 2, N'Awesome Collections', N'20151129115910', 1, CAST(0x0000A91900000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (4, 1, 2, N'Awesome Collections', N'20151129115910', 1, CAST(0x0000A8FC00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (5, 2, 2, N'Awesome Collections', N'20151129115912', 2, CAST(0x0000A8F300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (6, 1, 2, N'Joss Collections', N'20151129115912', 2, CAST(0x0000A8F400000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (7, 1, 4, N'Joss Collections', N'20151130120336', 1, CAST(0x0000A8DF00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (8, 1, 10, N'Awesome Collections', N'20151130120336', 1, CAST(0x0000A8BA00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (9, 2, 10, N'Awesome Collections', N'20151130120616', 1, CAST(0x0000A8BE00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (10, 1, 10, N'Joss Collections', N'20151130120616', 1, CAST(0x0000A8AB00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (11, 2, 12, N'Great', N'20151130125238', 2, CAST(0x0000A88700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (12, 1, 12, N'Great', N'20151130125238', 2, CAST(0x0000A86F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (13, 2, 4, N'Great', N'20151202085309', 6, CAST(0x0000A85700000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (14, 1, 10, N'Joss Collections', N'20151202085309', 6, CAST(0x0000A81E00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (15, 2, 10, N'Customer likes this a lot.', N'20151203101624', 1, CAST(0x0000A80F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (16, 2, 10, N'Customer likes this a lot.', N'20151203102205', 1, CAST(0x0000A7E500000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (17, 2, 2, N'Wao!! Great.', N'20151203103844', 1, CAST(0x0000A7CE00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (18, 1, 4, N'Just Awesome.', N'20151203103844', 1, CAST(0x0000A7BD00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (19, 2, 12, N'Customers just love the product.', N'20151203104143', 2, CAST(0x0000A78600000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (20, 1, 2, N'Awesome Collections.', N'20151203104143', 2, CAST(0x0000A79000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (21, 2, 6, N'Awesome Collections.', N'20151203104945', 1, CAST(0x0000A78F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (22, 1, 6, N'Great Collection.', N'20151203104945', 1, CAST(0x0000A79300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (23, 1, 10, N'Customer likes this a lot.', N'20151203105528', 1, CAST(0x0000A76F00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (24, 2, 4, N'Great Collection.', N'20151203105528', 1, CAST(0x0000A75300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (25, 2, 1, N'Just Great.', N'20151203110653', 7, CAST(0x0000A75C00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerInvoice] ([ID], [ProductID], [Quantity], [Details], [InvoiceID], [CustomerID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (26, 1, 1, N'Customers are happy with the product.', N'20151203110653', 7, CAST(0x0000A76400000000 AS DateTime))
```

**Update 1** - This calculation is done for last 12 months and please see how the quantity is calculated below:

```
Month-Year  Quantity
Jul 2018    80 (Sum of quantity from Jul 2018 to Jun 2017)  
Jun 2018    70 (Sum of quantity from Jun 2018 to May 2017)      
May 2018    42 (Sum of quantity from May 2018 to Apr 2017)      
Apr 2018    11 ...........................................  
Mar 2018    6  ...........................................  
Feb 2018    10 ...........................................  
Jan 2018    16 ...........................................
Dec 2017    1  ...........................................
..........................................................
Jun 2017    10 (Sum of quantity from Jun 2017 to May 2016)
```

Comment: you need a sum over() between preceding 12 or something. check around

Comment: actually scratch that, sql server 2008 does not suppoer rows between preceding :(

Comment: Note: your example does not include a "value" field to summate: do you want us to sum (quantity) instead?

Comment: It should sum the `quantity` column @George Menoutis. I'll check around the query that you have given - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the question for SQL Server 2012+ (the SQL Server version was not specified when I answered the question).

I would recommend using cumulative sums.  This assumes that you have data for each month, but that seems reasonable.  For a cumulative year-to-date:

```
SELECT YEAR(m.InvoiceDate) as yyyy,
       MONTH(m.InvoiceDate) as mm,
       SUM(m.Quantity) as Quantity,
       SUM(SUM(m.Quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate)
                                  ORDER BY MONTH(m.InvoiceDate)
                                 ) 
FROM CustomerInvoice m
WHERE YEAR(m.InvoiceDate) = 2018
GROUP BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate), MONTH(m.InvoiceDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate), MONTH(m.InvoiceDate);
```

Note that this uses `SUM(m.Quantity)` rather than `COUNT()`.  `SUM()` makes more sense based on your description.

If you want a cumulative running 12-month sum, ignoring year boundaries, use a windowing clause:

```
SELECT YEAR(m.InvoiceDate) as yyyy,
       MONTH(m.InvoiceDate) as mm,
       SUM(m.Quantity) as Quantity,
       SUM(SUM(m.Quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate)
                                  ORDER BY MONTH(m.InvoiceDate)
                                  ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                                 ) 
FROM CustomerInvoice m
GROUP BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate), MONTH(m.InvoiceDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate), MONTH(m.InvoiceDate);
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can express the first query as:

```
WITH ym as (
      SELECT YEAR(m.InvoiceDate) as yyyy,
             MONTH(m.InvoiceDate) as mm,
             SUM(m.Quantity) as Quantity,
      FROM CustomerInvoice m
      WHERE YEAR(m.InvoiceDate) = 2018
      GROUP BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate), MONTH(m.InvoiceDate)
     )
SELECT ym.yyyymm, ym.quantity, ym2.sum_Quantity)
FROM ym CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(ym2.quantity) as sum_quantity
      FROM ym ym2
      WHERE ym.yyyy = ym2.yyyy AND ym2.month <= ym.month
     ) ym2
ORDER BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate), MONTH(m.InvoiceDate);
```

For a rolling sum in SQL Server 2008:

```
WITH ym as (
      SELECT YEAR(m.InvoiceDate) as yyyy,
             MONTH(m.InvoiceDate) as mm,
             SUM(m.Quantity) as Quantity,
      FROM CustomerInvoice m
      WHERE YEAR(m.InvoiceDate) = 2018
      GROUP BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate), MONTH(m.InvoiceDate)
     )
SELECT ym.yyyymm, ym.quantity, ym2.sum_Quantity)
FROM ym CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(ym2.quantity) as sum_quantity
      FROM ym ym2
      WHERE ym2.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(year, -1, ym.InvoiceDate) AND
            ym2.InvoiceDate <= ym.InvoiceDate
     ) ym2
ORDER BY YEAR(m.InvoiceDate), MONTH(m.InvoiceDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gordon Linoff and it run successfully. Though I've one thing to clear - You have done cumulative sum here and please see my updated post.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff and it works perfectly. Though I am trying to figure out how it works right now and really appreciate your hard work as well time - Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH t (month_name,month_id,quantity)  
AS  
(  
    select month_name,month_id,quantity
    from CustomerInvoice
    cross apply (select datediff(month,0,InvoiceDate) month_id,format(InvoiceDate,'MMMM yyyy') month_name)stats
)  
SELECT months_tbl.*,sum(quantity) from 
(select distinct month_name,month_id from t)months_tbl
inner join t on t.month_id between months_tbl.month_id-11 and months_tbl.month_id
group by months_tbl.month_name,months_tbl.month_id
order by month_id asc
```

Comment: Getting this - `'format' is not a recognized built-in function name` @George Menoutis.

Comment: I was able to run the query and it seems ok, I guess @George Menoutis. I tried to filter it with a `WHERE` clause using a specific year say **2018**. But it returned nothing - I used the clause after the `AS` statement. I believe, it'll return accurate data using year filter.

Comment: ah yes, format() is not supported by 2008 - just replace it with the function that creates the month-year string. Filtering by year should work - just add a WHERE InvoiceDate>= '20180101' and InvoiceDate<'20190101' in the CTE (the "AS" part). What WHERE did you use? Paste the code to see what went wrong

Comment: Please see my updated post and thanks for the answer @George Menoutis.